# How to check if table relationship is one to many in SSMS

Tags: sql, ssms

I'm writing some SQL code based on my tables but don't want to miss any edge cases. I'm wondering how do you check if there's a one to many relationship between two tables in SSMS

```
SELECT *
FROM Houses
JOIN Addresses 
     on Houses.Id = Addresses.HouseId
```

Unfortunately the data when queried doesn't give me any insight.

What I tried to do:

Checked table dependencies but that didn't give me any insight. It shows addresses are dependencies but no relationship details.

May I ask, is it possible to determine if one to one via SSMS?

Comment: There's no simple way to determine this - if, for your example, you're expecting to maybe look at a foreign key and it has a tick-box to say whether it's "one-to-one" or "one-to-many".  You could in theory look at foreign key columns and determine any unique indexes that are applied to them ....... but, to be honest, the way the relationships are is driven by the business requirements behind that data.  If you're working with a database (whether putting data in, or querying data from it) you'd infer the relationship info from the business need.  What is your particular use case?

Comment: Why do you think you would miss data with that query?  There is a relationship between Houses and Addresses and you are selecting ALL the Houses and ALL the related Addresses.    If a Houses.Id value had 2 matching Addresses.HouseId values in the Addresses table then you would get 2 rows back.  There is no filter in your query to say only give me the first related record.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query to determine how many values each house in the two tables.  Well, in this case, we'll assume it is the primary key of `houses` and the values of `HouseId` are valid ids:

```
SELECT num_addresses, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT h.Id, COUNT(a.HouseId) as num_addresses
      FROM Houses h LEFT JOIN
           Addresses a
           ON h.Id = a.HouseId
      GROUP BY h.Id
     ) ha
GROUP BY num_addresses;
```

Then interpret the results:

- If the only row returned has `num_addresses` of `1`, then you have a 1-1 relationship.
- If two rows are returns with values of `0` and `1`, then you have a 1/0-1 relationship.
- If multiple rows are returned and the minimum is `1` then you have a 1-n.
  If multiple rows are returned and the minimum value is `0`, then you have a `0-n`.

You could extend this for more general relationships, but this answers the question you asked here.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between tables is shown by things called 'DATABASE - DIAGRAM'
Here is document about how to create database - diagram in SSMS.
[How to create database diagram SSMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6269/sql-server-database-diagram-tool-in-management-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff response is perfect for the helicopter view -

To get all records side by side simply select all columns from both tables side by side with the left join

```
SELECT Houses.*, Address.*
FROM Houses 
left JOIN Addresses on Addresses.HouseId = Houses.Id
union all
SELECT Houses.*, Address.*
FROM Addresses 
left JOIN Houses  on  Houses.Id = Addresses.HouseId
```

Microsoft have implemented a reduced code method to do the same but I have not explored it so could not comment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/outer-joins?view=sql-server-ver15

What will be apparent is you will see Houses.ID and Addresses.HouseID side by side - An empty value in either means that the relevant table does not have a record for the relevant HouseID or ID

You can then cherry pick those edge case records as you see fit